# Using Akka (with Java) how can I verify that my actor under test is watching another actor?

Tags: java, unit-testing, akka

I have the following actor for which I would like to create unit tests to verify the following behaviour:

1. `ListeningActor` correctly registers itself to watch the `listeningTo` actor.
2. `ListeningActor` correctly kills itself when the `listeningTo` actor terminates.

How can I verify these two behaviours?

I am using Akka 2.0.2 with Java.

Thanks

```java
public class ListeningActor extends UntypedActor {
    private final ActorRef listeningTo;

    public ListeningActor(final ActorRef listeningTo) {
        this.listeningTo = listeningTo;
    }

    @Override
    public void preStart() {
        super.preStart();
        context().watch(listeningTo);          // <---- To verify
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Object o) throws Exception {
        if (o instanceof Terminated) {
            Terminated terminated = (Terminated) o;
            if (terminated.equals(listeningTo)) {
                context().stop(self());        // <---- To verify
            }
        } else {
            unhandled(o);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Watch the ListenerActor with the testActor from TestKit, then expect the ListenerActor to be Terminated when you PoisonPill and-or stop an actor it listens to. Done.

Comment: Thanks, that was easier than I thought. And it caught a bug - the if condition should have been written as `if (terminated.actor().equals(listeningTo))`

Answer (score 5):

If it helps anyone, here's my final unit test:

```
public class ListeningActorTest
{
    private TestKit testKit;
    private TestActorRef<ListeningActor> listeningActor;
    private TestProbe listeningToActor;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception
    {
        testKit = new TestKit(ActorSystem.apply());
        listeningToActor = TestProbe.apply(testKit.system());
        listeningActor = TestActorRef.apply(new Props(new UntypedActorFactory()
        {
            @Override
            public Actor create()
            {
                return new ListeningActor(listeningToActor.ref());
            }
        }), testKit.system());
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldTerminateWhenTheListeningToActorTerminates()
    {
        //Given
        assertFalse(listeningActor.isTerminated());

        //When
        listeningToActor.testActor().tell(PoisonPill.getInstance());

        //Then
        assertTrue(listeningActor.isTerminated());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using JavaTestKit and akka version 2.4.2 you could solve it like this:

```
@Test
public void testThatPersistenceActorShutdown() {
    watch(persistenceActor);
    persistenceActor.tell(new Shutdown(), getRef());
    expectTerminated(persistenceActor);
}
```

You can find a working example here - [akka-persistence-java-example](https://github.com/jansoren/akka-persistence-java-example/)

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I am not familiar with akka.

Can you subclass ActorRef? If so, you can make a subclass specifically for testing which you can cause to send messages and be terminated. Then, in your unit tests, tell your instance of ListeningActor to be terminated, and verify that your ListeningActor instance has been stopped.

Comment: Thank you Eric. I am actually hoping to use a solution that includes Akka's TestKit. I want to ensure that the `context().watch()` and `context().stop()` methods are called correctly.